# Sitemap does not look at .htaccess rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website where i have the url rewriting rules written in the .htaccess file. The rules are working fine there. for example the troublesome rule is that .php is removed from the url. This works fine on the browser. But when i generate the sitemap it some how picks the .php and generates the sitemap accordingly.

Is that some of the pages have .php written in the links ?

Is there any way that the sitemap generator should actually bring into consideration the url rewriting rules ?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: What are you using to generate the sitemap?

Comment: The .htaccess has **no** effect while creating the sitemap. You should define the rules inside the sitemap generator.